# ZoomUS not working with Expo React Native (Null Exception Occurred)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, zoom-sdk

```
    import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Button, Alert } from "react-native";
import { KJUR } from 'jsrsasign';
import ZoomUs from "react-native-zoom-us";


const CLIENT_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
const CLIENT_SECRET = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';


const EducationZoom = () => {
  const [isInitialized, setIsInitialized] = useState(false);
   useEffect(() => {
     (async () => {
       try{
         const message = await ZoomUs.initialize({
           clientKey: CLIENT_KEY,
           clientSecret: CLIENT_SECRET,
         })

         console.log('message is ', message);
         setIsInitialized(true);
       }catch(error){
         Alert.alert('error is ', error.toString());
       }

     })();
   },[]);


   return (
     <Button title={"Join a meeting"} disabled={!isInitialized}/>
   )
};

export default EducationZoom;'
```

After I use this code, the error is shown below. So to solve this error I changed the versions of dependencies. But not be solved. Please give me a suitable solution for this.

Used Technologies (Expo, React Native, ZoomUS)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need to eject from using expo, this dependency needs to be linked to the native side of react-native (bridged)
[Expo Ejection](https://docs.expo.dev/archive/glossary/)

or you might have to do eas build with the plugin introduced in the library react-native-zoom-us so check its documentation

Comment: How to declare plugins using expo ?

Comment: @ParindaSathsara https://docs.expo.dev/guides/config-plugins/#ios-app-delegate